# is it possible to set multiple values in a specific json body field in the contract?

Tags: groovy, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

for example, I have dto with 2 **required** fields: name and age.
If i use Spring Cloud Contract then I need to describe several files with contracts:

1. where request body is `{"name": "test", "age": 99}`
2. where request body is `{"name": null, "age": 99}`
3. where request body is `{"name": "test", "age": null}`

or I can describe it in one contract and several tests will be generated from it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you open the documentation of Spring Cloud Contract (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current/reference/html/project-features.html#contract-dsl) you will see it being written in one of the first sentences.

> Spring Cloud Contract supports defining multiple contracts in a single
> file.

There's even a whole section about it https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current/reference/html/project-features.html#contract-dsl-multiple

```
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

[
    Contract.make {
        name("should post a user")
        request {
            method 'POST'
            url('/users/1')
        }
        response {
            status OK()
        }
    },
    Contract.make {
        request {
            method 'POST'
            url('/users/2')
        }
        response {
            status OK()
        }
    }
]
```

Before asking questions please always read the documentation.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the question was not how to combine files with contracts, but how to describe one contract file.  something like that: ```name:values(test, null)```

Comment: You can describe this in one file with 3 different contracts